# How did Lincoln Lee know Nick Lane?

Tags: fringe

In S2E22 of *Fringe*, "Over There, Part 1", Walter Bishop, Sally Clark, Nick Lane, and Olivia Dunham travel to the Redverse. Its Fringe Division chase and surround them on a bridge, where Lincoln seems to recognize Nick and asks

> Nick?

But even though I've seen the whole show (except for the final episodes), it is never revealed how they knew each other, it's fair to say that there's probably a Nick Lane on the Redverse as well, but it's never disclosed how Redverse's Lincoln Lee and Nick Lane knew each other, or is it?

Comment: The Cortexiphan trials did not happen Over There, so his life would have been almost completely different.  I doubt don't think there's an answer to this unless someone asked the writers directly..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lincoln and Nick knew each other over there when they were younger and Lincoln even dated Nick's sister.

In S4E20, "Worlds Apart", we see Nick Lane from over there meet agent Lee from over here, thinking it's Lincoln from over there:

> Lincoln, hi. I'm Nick Lane.
>   I don't know if you remember me, but we grew up in the same neighbourhood in Philly. I was a couple of years behind you in school.
>   You went out with my sister, Kendra.

So when Lincoln Lee from over there saw Nick Lane from over here, he thought he recognised a childhood friend.

Comment: @TrishLing Thank you for adding the link, but I didn't use it in finding the answer, so I feel it's out of place here. I _would_ like to link to a script or transcript, but this episode is incomplete on Fringepedia.

Comment: Here's a link to [a transcript](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=fringe&episode=s04e20)-unfornately the way springfieldspringfield.co.uk does episode/movie transcripts, it really is just the dialogue, no character name or anything- but the pertinent lines are there.

Comment: I was going to add the answer since I rewatched the show but you beat me to it.